# Passing self (function)

Tags: javascript, class, function-pointers

`I wasn't sure what it was called, but I was trying to have a function return a reference to it's self. Thank you very much`

This is very hard for me to explain (which might be why I haven't been able to find any usable google results)

This is an example however, that will show you what I mean

```
this.test = function(foo){
    return this.test;    //The function is namespaced 
}
```

I hope that explains what I'm trying to do here. I don't have too much hope in this working, but I'm just beginning to write bigger javascript objects so I'm running into a lot of weirdness I'm not used to (classes in JavaScript aren't exactly forward)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can't see any logic here. You try to make the function return reference to itself?

Comment: yes I'm trying to get the function to return a reference to itself. Thank's again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the inner and outer `this.test` are not the same because `this` is not the same in each scope.

to write a function that returns itself (although I'm not sure why you would want to do that) try this:

```
var that = this;
that.test = function () {
    return that.test;
}
```

In your example `this.test` will always return undefined

Comment: I would just name the function expression, e.g. `this.test = function test(foo){return test;};`

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while, I had to travel for a couple of days, but I'm testing this right now. (Also, yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to get a function to return it's self.)

Comment: IT WORKS !!! thank's A TONNE @Greg Guida and CMS  

If I could give you guys more points I would. Cheers ! http://jsfiddle.net/qjJwP/2

Answer (score 0):

what you posted wont actually do anything.
this will "do something"

```
 myName={};

myName.test = function(foo){
    return foo;    
}

 alert( myName.test("hello"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Johnny . I really appreciate it. Cheers.